# wicket 9: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.my.gui.event.MyEvent

Tags: wicket

I'm using event to indicate to other parts of a system that an action needs to be
performed.

```java
    public class MyEvent {
        private final AjaxRequestTarget target;
        private final LoadableDetachableModel<MyItem> item;
        private final LoadableDetachableModel<ToolbarModel> myToolbar;
        public MyEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target, MyItem item,
                                  MyToolbar myToolbar) {
            this.target = target;
            this.item = LoadableDetachableModel.of(() -> item);
            this.myToolbar = LoadableDetachableModel.of(() -> myToolbar);
        }
    
        public LoadableDetachableModel<MyToolbar> getMyToolbar() {
            return myToolbar;
        }
    
        public AjaxRequestTarget getTarget() {
            return target;
        }
    
        public LoadableDetachableModel<MyItem> getItem() {
            return item;
        }
    }
```

I send this event using a piece of code

```java
    ...
    send(component, Broadcast.EXACT,new MyEvent(target, item, myToolbar));
    ...
```

and I catch this event using

```java
    @Override
    public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event) {
        super.onEvent(event);
        if (event.getPayload() instanceof MyEvent) {
            performAction((MyEvent) event.getPayload());
        }
    }
```

However, I'm experiencing an error / exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 'data' may not be null.
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Args.notNull(Args.java:41) ~[wicket-util-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.SerializedPage.<init>(SerializedPage.java:64) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.SerializingPageStore.addPage(SerializingPageStore.java:80) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.CachingPageStore.addPage(CachingPageStore.java:73) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.RequestPageStore.detach(RequestPageStore.java:114) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageManager.detach(PageManager.java:91) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Application$2.onDetach(Application.java:1582) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$3.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:105) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$3.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:101) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection$1.notify(ListenerCollection.java:120) [wicket-util-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.reversedNotify(ListenerCollection.java:144) [wicket-util-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.reversedNotifyIgnoringExceptions(ListenerCollection.java:113) [wicket-util-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection.onDetach(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:100) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.onDetach(RequestCycle.java:670) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.detach(RequestCycle.java:625) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:285) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:208) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:307) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) [spring-boot-actuator-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

and

```
org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream$ObjectCheckException: The object type is not Serializable!
A problem occurred while checking object with type: com.my.gui.event.MyEvent
Field hierarchy is:
  0 [class=com.my.gui.my.page, path=0]
    private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=java.util.ArrayList]
      private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children[write:20][write:21] [class=com.my.gui.event.pagePanel, path=0:tablePanel]
        java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.Component.data [class=[Ljava.lang.Object;]
          java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.Component.data[0] [class=org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel]
            final org.danekja.java.util.function.serializable.SerializableSupplier org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel$1.val$getter [class=com.my.gui.my.page$$Lambda$1236/0x0000000800c56c40]
              private final java.lang.Object[] java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.capturedArgs [class=[Ljava.lang.Object;]
                private final java.lang.Object[] java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.capturedArgs[0] [class=com.my.gui.event.MyEvent] <----- field that is causing the problem
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:371) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:354) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:413) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:354) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.checkFields(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:607) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:545) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:354) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.checkFields(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:607) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:545) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:354) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:413) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:354) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.checkFields(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:607) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:545) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:354) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream$1InterceptingObjectOutputStream.replaceObject(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:501) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1145) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:897) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1145) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:509) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:354) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.checkFields(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:607) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:545) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:354) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:711) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:345) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer$SerializationCheckerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JavaSerializer.java:394) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:345) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer.serialize(JavaSerializer.java:97) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.SerializingPageStore.addPage(SerializingPageStore.java:80) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.CachingPageStore.addPage(CachingPageStore.java:73) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.RequestPageStore.detach(RequestPageStore.java:114) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageManager.detach(PageManager.java:91) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Application$2.onDetach(Application.java:1582) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$3.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:105) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$3.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:101) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection$1.notify(ListenerCollection.java:120) [wicket-util-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.reversedNotify(ListenerCollection.java:144) [wicket-util-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.reversedNotifyIgnoringExceptions(ListenerCollection.java:113) [wicket-util-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection.onDetach(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:100) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.onDetach(RequestCycle.java:670) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.detach(RequestCycle.java:625) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:285) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:208) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:307) [wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) [spring-security-web-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) [spring-boot-actuator-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at 
org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer$SerializationCheckerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JavaSerializer.java:383) ~[wicket-core-9.4.0.jar:9.4.0]
    ... 87 more
```

As I understand I do get this error / exception, because myEvent is not serializable, do I have to make events serializable? To me it makes no sense to serialize events. Is there a wicket way to avoid these two issues (see stacktraces)? What to do?

Comment: Hi miroana, please check if both MyItem and ToolbarModel classes implement Serializable interface. I checked an example and event do not implement Serializable https://examples9x.wicket.apache.org/events/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.events.DecoupledAjaxUpdatePage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your event keeps `LoadableDetachable` models, I assume that some of your listening components will use them as their own model:

```java
public void performAction(MyEvent event) {
  setModel(event.getItem());
}
```

As the stacktrace clearly shows, it is the `SerializableSupplier` lambda you give to `LoadableDetachableModel.of()`, that keeps a reference to the surrounding event class.

Drop the `LoadableDetachableModels`. They don't make sense, since the objects inside them are already there and won't be 'loaded' anyways.